# Web UI automated test works on desktop Chrome, but can find elements in Android Chrome

Tags: java, selenium, appium

I have test for some web-page, written on Java, with Selenium and JUnit. It opens web page, located element by ID, type text into it.
Before test, I create WebDriver object: 
WebDriver driver
and create driver as usual:

```
driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

All is working correct.

Now I am trying to run same test, but on Android device with Chrome driver.
So, I init my driver in this way:

```
driver = new AppiumDriver(new URL("..."), caps);
```

My test can be launcher, Android device opens mobile Chrome and opens my web page.
But then I get exception saying that element not found:

```
Returned value cannot be converted to WebElement: {message=no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"text"}
```

I am sure, page structure is the same, so that element is located on page and I can see it. But by some reason in mobile web all findElelemnt commands does not work.

So, my question is what should I test to be able run my test on mobile browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason was a bug in web-site under test. Element in mobile version has different name.